# Unexpected line break in JSDoc

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm getting a line break in a jsDoc popup and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Here's what the popup looks like with the @param tag, as expected:

[image]

---

---

But if I add a new line below it, the tag is split for some reason:

[image]

---

**Update:** So far, the only way I've found to fix it is adding a meaningless "@" sign:

[image]

Comment: 2BH with you man, its 99.9999% likely a JSDoc thing. JSDoc is kinda sorta a crappy technology. Your experiancing what everyone else experiances when using it. Its very hard to format, and often times it adds or removes formatting when it shouldn't. What I mean by shouldn't is that typically Markdown doesn't behave in the way that markdown behaves in JSDoc.